# MYSQL keeps getting killed during innodb recovery

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

MYSQL is getting killed, and from the error log file it looks like its during the innodb crash recovery process. At the moment if I restart MYSQL, it stays up for about 5 or 10 minutes, then gets killed.

I've run `MySQLTuner` to see if that brought up anything useful, and its only suggestion was to increase the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. I did that, but it doesn't seem to have helped.

The below is a snippet of the error log file from when it was last killed.

```
180307 17:35:02  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 1121705399
180307 17:35:02  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
180307 17:35:02  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
180307 17:35:03 InnoDB: 5.5.44 started; log sequence number 1121705399
180307 17:35:03 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
180307 17:35:03 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
180307 17:35:03 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
180307 17:35:03 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
180307 17:35:03 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.44-0+deb7u1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Debian)
Killed
180307 17:40:01 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
180307 17:40:01 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
180307 17:40:01 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
180307 17:40:01 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.44-0+deb7u1) starting as process 24344 ...
180307 17:40:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
180307 17:40:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180307 17:40:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
180307 17:40:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
180307 17:40:01 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
180307 17:40:01 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
Killed
180307 17:40:02 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

The Mysqltuner report is:

```
-------- General Statistics --------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.44-0+deb7u1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 888M (Tables: 24)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 24

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 22s (113 q [5.136 qps], 41 conn, TX: 19K, RX: 7K)
[--] Reads / Writes: 100% / 0%
[--] Total buffers: 192.0M global + 2.7M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 597.8M (7% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/113)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 0% (1/151)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0M/97.0K
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 0.0% (0 cached / 71 selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 20% (54 on disk / 267 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 97% (1 created / 41 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 90% (65 open / 72 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 4% (48/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (62 immediate / 62 locks)
[!!] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 888.0M/128.0M

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 888M)
```

and SHOW GLOBAL STATUS output: https://pastebin.com/A2Zrsu8m

and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES output: https://pastebin.com/DPp7WC99

Any advice on where to look or what to do to diagnose this issue further would be appreciated.

Comment: Try *lowering* that value. You might simply run out of memory.

Comment: @Solarflare It was at 64Mb before, and this was still happening. The recommendation from mysqltuner was to increase it to be at least the size of my innodb data size (910Mb). I increased it to 1G, it was still happening, so I increased it to 2G which is when the snippet above came from.

Comment: The recommendation is for increased performance, MySQLTuner doesn't look for the reason your process crashes. There is no obvious reason for a crash in the log, but insufficient ram can have that effect, which is why I suggested to lowering it (Linux will kill the process if it runs low on memory). It might still not be low enough, so check your available ram. Also check your system logs, it might contain more details.

Comment: I agree, you should check how much memory you actually have before increasing the buffer pool. Use `free -m` on Linux. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81222 describes a case where the word "Killed" in the error log indicates that the Linux out-of-memory killer terminated the mysqld process.

Comment: I did check before I increased it. There's 8G free on the machine. Lowering it hasn't helped either.

Comment: Please post your complete Mysqltuner report and we will have many clues quickly on the table.  Also post (if not here, to pastebin.com) results of 
current complete my.cnf/ini 
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
C) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
D) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop   OR  top for most active apps 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device
  Will try to assist.

Comment: It looks like your ini has key_buffer  rather than key_buffer_size, changing it will get rid of the deprecated message.

Comment: @nick  Thanks for your Mysqltuner report. Now we can determine you have 8G RAM.  If you could post text results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; minimum, we may be able to assist.  What version and OS are you using?

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've added those to the main post. Put them on pastebin as they're a bit long to just add to this post. The OS is Debian 7.9

Comment: @nick  Are you still crashing during recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions for your my.cnf/ini [mysqld] section

```
key_buffer_size=1M  # from 16M  MyISAM will be used very little, if at all
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G  # from 128M  and will be 1/4 of total RAM appx
innodb_log_file_size=1G  # from 5M which is LESS than buffer-size = BAD
innodb_print_all_deadlocks=ON  # from OFF - review error log daily
log_warnings=2  # from 1 to know when connections were rejected and possibly why.
max_allowed_packet=1M  # from 16M  RAM could be REQD per CONNECTION
```

if you need more than 1M MAP, in your SESSION
SET @max_allowed_packet=1000000000  1G abbreviation not permitted.  Max of INfile size.

and for quicker KNOWEDGE of WHY it crashes in less than 15 minutes,

```
general_log=ON  # from OFF  so you have a total track prior to the crash.
```

If it runs 20 minutes due to these ini updates, you MUST turn OFF the 
GENERAL LOG BEFORE you have a FULL hard drive!.
Keep me posted.  And please post 
A) complete Mysqltuner report
B) ulimit -a     so we can verify your open_files_limit is no more 80% of available
C) iostat  -x    at a busy time so we know IOPS achieved at that time.

If it is still crashing, please post 
last 400 lines of GENERAL_LOG
last 500 lines of ERROR_LOG
repost SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES.
When CRASHED, SHOW GLOBAL STATUS can not be gathered up.

Thanks for your earlier posts today that allowed this analysis.

Comment: The database still crashed every 10-15mins. I decided to just move the database to a different (more up to date) server. Thats sorted it out.

Comment: Nick,  excellent move.  I wondered about the version you were running.
Please pick up my contact info from the Profile here for the future.